# Session time outs and locking on different browsers

Tags: php, session, timeout

I have looked through a few previously answered questions, but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

So I have a simple login script that looks like the following:

### login.php

```
// If page requires SSL, and we're not in SSL mode, 
// redirect to the SSL version of the page
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
// put sha1() encrypted password here
$password = 'sha1passwordgoeshere';

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if (sha1($_POST['password']) == $password) {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    } else {
        $logFailure = true;
    }
} 

if (!$_SESSION['loggedIn']): 
// Load Login Page
exit();
endif;
```

### logout.php

```
// If page requires SSL, and we're not in SSL mode, 
// redirect to the SSL version of the page
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}

// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

The rest of my pages include login.php at the top of the file.

All seems to work fine, most of the time. However, I have been noticing since I have moved over to a new server, and using php 5.6.14 that I have been getting timed out from time to time.

For example, right now I can login with Internet Explorer, but I can't with Firefox or Chrome. If I clear cookies, I can then login with Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not Chrome.

### UPDATE

I can cause a timeout immediately by logging in successfully, logging out immediately, then logging in again. On the second login, it times out.

It is really been frustrating me, and I am not a session guru, so I don't understand why it is acting in this way, or how to fix it so that it isn't so delicate.

I am only using sessions to record the login, and not for anything else. I do use AJAX on certain pages within the site, but not often.

**Basically, I never want this to time out. How would I prevent these time outs from happening?**

Comment: If you're only recording the login, would a Cookie work?

Comment: Sure, but I thought I was already using a cookie by using a session?

Comment: A cookie is created. But your script is not looking at it specifically. Since a session has to have a timeout, it will always die eventually. You can create a cookie to live for a much longer period of time. The scripts can see if the cookie you created exists instead of a live session. Not a good practice but would prevent the issue you're encountering.

Comment: I see. Is there anything wrong with my code? This didn't happen before I moved servers, so I don't know if the php version update is causing an issue or the Apache co figuration

Comment: When you say, in the 2nd login, it times out, how do you know this?

Comment: @Twisty - because the page just sits there endlessly loading. I can refresh, try to enter URL again, and it will never load.

Also, I believe I have fixed the issue now.

First, I had used a form button the log out page to allow a user to log back in. I replaced that with a standard link.

Second, after login, the landing page had a section of code that would create error warnings on the log file with a foreach expecting an array (even though it was an array and outputted properly). Removing that section of code seems to have fixed the issue.

I am not sure how this would cause problems.

Comment: glad you figured it out, sort of. I can't speak to that since I can only see the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. First, I had used a form button on the log out page to allow a user to log back in. I replaced that with a standard link.

Second, after login, the landing page had a section of code that would create error warnings on the log file with a foreach expecting an array (even though it was an array and outputted properly). Removing that section of code seems to have fixed the issue. I am not sure how this would cause problems.